# Statement doesn't return all entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm calling a linq statement that doesn't appear to be working correctly:

My Client Model:

```
public class Client
{

    [UIHint("Hidden")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("Hidden")]
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    [UIHint("Hidden")]
    public int GenderId { get; set; }
    public string GenderDescription { get; set; }

    [UIHint("Hidden")]
    public int SettingId { get; set; }

    public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public virtual Setting Setting { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}
```

My Linq Call:

```
var clients = db.Clients.Include(c => c.Gender).Include(c => c.Setting).Include(c => c.UserProfile).OrderBy(c => c.ClientId);
```

This will populate both the Gender and Setting fields with the proper info based off of the GenderId and SettingId, but the UserProfile does not. Is there a rational explanation or do I need to keep beating my head against the desk?

Comment: Have you tried tracing the query?

Comment: I've put in breakpoint just after `var clients` and look at the Results View and it returns null for UserProfile

Comment: Questions I ask myself when I encounter issues like this: 1. does UserProfile contain data? 2. is UserProfile class set up correctly (like Gender and Setting)? 3. is there a FK relationship on the schema in the db?

Comment: Are you using sql server? Try using the sql server profiler to get the generated query. See whether you get any data with the generated query.

Comment: Provide following details :

1. Version of entity framework
2. What is a database ?
3. String query = clients.ToString() >> Please write the query text here
4. Are you have any custome mapping for your classes ?

Comment: Ok after some fighting with this I realized that when I created the UserProfile model that I used UserId instead of UserProfileId which was a pain to updated throughout my app (but that is another story altogether).

Comment: Thanks for everyone's reply, it takes a little prodding sometimes to get you to see the obvious! Also your comments have given me great resources for troubleshooting problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I had was that when I created the UserProfile Model I used UserId instead of UserProfileId. The framework kept looking for an Id that did not exist.

The proper model should look like this:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile()
    {
        this.Casefiles = new HashSet<Casefile>();
    }

    [Display(Name="Author")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; }
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    // UserInRole Level
    public string Role { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Request Account Uplevel to Contributor")]
    public bool RequestUplevel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Casefile> Casefiles { get; set; }

}
```

This way when you make a call like:

```
var clients = db.Clients.Include(c => c.Gender)
                        .Include(c => c.Setting)
                        .Include(c => c.UserProfile)
                        .OrderBy(c => c.ClientId)
                        .Where(u => u.UserProfileId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

This will return each of the virtual calls in the Client Model.